# Why would a linkedin embed button not display

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to embed a linked Apply now button to a website, I manage to generate the button and input my api_key but when i copy the code onto the website I get absolutely noting below is the code i'm using.

```
   <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
      api_key: MY_API_KEY
    </script>
    <script type="IN/Apply" data-companyid="THE_COMPANY_ID" data-jobtitle="Test Job" data-joblocation="Sweden" data-email="ACCOUN_EMAIL"></script>
```

Has anyone experience this issue if so how do you fix it?

Comment: Does the JavaScript console display any errors? Does the Net tab of your developer tools show that the script is successfully loading? Do you have any adblock or privacy protector software running?

Comment: When you I embed the code I get the following error message in google chrome console "You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration."

Comment: So, do Step 2 of https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api

Comment: I already have the API ID, but still getting the error message

Comment: The error message is saying that you didn't set up the domain correctly when you got the ID. See the screenshot for step 2. What value are you putting there? What is the URL in your browser's address bar when the script fails?